# setting up for programming using webGL

Tags: webgl

I am having problems for setting up my laptop to program using webGL.
I am using mint linux 16. I tried installing nodejs because the webGL is javascript program but it seems not working. I am reading a book called WebGL programming guide and try to run an example in the book to make sure that my laptop is set up for webgl. One of the very first example in the book uses javascript libraries such as webgl-utils.js, webgl-debug.js... but I can find those libraries. Can anyone help me please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check to see if your video card or browser is supported.

http://get.webgl.org/

http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/BlacklistsAndWhitelists

Comment: Thanks for ur comment. I am using the latest version of firefox and it works fine. What I am trying to do is make webGL program. I mean that I write a javascript js file using a text editor and embed it into a html file. The thing is that the book I mentioned above sing some webgl libraries which are js files and I could not locate those libraries.

Comment: You could always google a section of the code. Sometimes you'll find the libraries on github or on the publisher website that way. You might also want to check out http://threejs.org/. Best of luck!

Comment: Try [this site](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217). Each example is embedded in the page so you can check if they run in your browser. I think he uses some extra sources as well so be sure you've got them all when you try running them locally.